# Bind touch events and avoid scrolling in Internet Explorer (11)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, canvas, touch

I have problem  with touch events in IE. Here is my example:

```
fiddle example (scroll bottom right box to down)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bordeux/78fez12m/2/

When i use Internet Explorer and i want draw line from top to bottom, all page is scrolling. How can i stop scrolling webpage, when user is drawing on canvas?

Answer (score 0):

fixed it for ie touch http://jsfiddle.net/h1d1djcr/

```
 <style>canvas {     touch-action: double-tap-zoom; } </style>
```